# Rails自体のactionviewのテストが失敗する

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Contributing to Ruby on Rails — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html)を読んで
[rails/rails-dev-box: A virtual machine for Ruby on Rails core development](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box)を入れました。

`vagrant@rails-dev-box:/vagrant/rails/actionview$ bundle exec rake test`
と`/vagrant/rails/actionview`ディレクトリでtestを実行してみましたが
最後に

```
  1) Failure:
RenderTest#test_render_action_upcased [/vagrant/rails/actionview/test/actionpack/controller/render_test.rb:742]:
ActionView::MissingTemplate expected but nothing was raised.

220 runs, 307 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -w -I"lib:test" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/actionpack/abstract/abstract_controller_test.rb" "test/actionpack/abstract/helper_test.rb" "test/actionpack/abstract/layouts_test.rb" "test/actionpack/abstract/render_test.rb" "test/actionpack/controller/capture_test.rb" "test/actionpack/controller/layout_test.rb" "test/actionpack/controller/render_test.rb" "test/actionpack/controller/view_paths_test.rb" ]

Tasks: TOP => test => test:integration:action_pack
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

となって終了します。

テストに使っているRails自体は
[rails/rails at 4-2-stable: Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/4-2-stable)
(コミット番号: e531c86e6bb0b623cd18c97a7a32ba981e8fb2ce)
でして

Code Statusが`build passing`なのでテストに失敗することがそもそもおかしいと思うのですが、認識が違っているのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box/issues/116#issuecomment-189119225

> Please note that in the current dev box the distro is "ubuntu/wily64".
>
> Regarding the tests, skips are a decision of the project. The failure in Action View is known, it has to do with running a case-insensitive filesystem in Linux basically. Please do ignore that one, your setup seems to be fine.

ということで、失敗することで知られているようでした。
(とはいえ`Code Status`が`build passing`なのが気になる）

Answer (score 1):

VPSで実行してみましたが

```
220 runs, 307 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

となり正常に終了しましたので認識はあっているかと思います。
テストコードを編集されてたりはしませんか？

実行環境は、同じく `4-2-stable` ブランチで `e531c86e6bb0b623cd18c97a7a32ba981e8fb2ce` をcheckoutしました。
また、rubyのversionは `2.3.0p0` です。